# Mybaits resultMap without column, use columnIndex instead

Tags: db2, mybatis, ibatis

I am migrating from ibatis to mybatis, in ibatis it supported result set without column names just using columnNumber, but looks like this is not supported in mybatis,
what is the best way to get it working in mybatis,

Ibatis this works

```
<resultMap id="resultMap" type="com.test.data.MyObject">    
    <result property="key"                   columnIndex="1"/>
    <result property="number"                columnIndex="2"/>
</resultMap>
```

in mybatis columnIndex like this is not supported it needs column name.

Comment: You are going to have to use column label or name, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, there's no column index anymore.